# Scrambled arguments when building OpenJDK

Tags: makefile, java

When trying to build OpenJDK, I get a series of errors while doing `make all`:

```
/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- '8'
/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- '/'
/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- 'a'
/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- '/'
/usr/bin/make: invalid option -- 'c'
```

Running `make all LOG=trace JOBS=1` gives

```
+ /usr/bin/make VERBOSE= LOG_LEVEL=trace -R -I /home/ft/openjdk8/make/common -f adlc.make -r -rRw -I/home/ft/open -j1 -dk8/make/common -I/home/ft/openjdk8/make/common -I/home/ft/openjdk8/make/common -I/home/ft/openjdk8/make/common -I/home/ft/openjdk8/make/common
```

as the bad argument. The relevent section is `-I/home/ft/open -j1 -dk8/make/common`. `grep -R 'I/home/ft/open -j1 -dk8/make/common'` turns up nothing more than the log. This occurs with `./configure --enable-debug` and without.

I found an [issue on a mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/build-dev/2013-October/010840.html) that seems similar, but it appears that he gave up.

**Edit:** Searched for `-ji`, `make/HotspotWrapper.gmk`:`@($(CD) $(HOTSPOT_TOPDIR)/make && $(MAKE) -j1 $(HOTSPOT_MAKE_ARGS) SPEC=$(HOTSPOT_SPEC) BASE_SPEC=$(BASE_SPEC))` is the main candidate for breaking things

Comment: Something is running a replacement like `s/jd/j1 -/` and that is turning `I/home/ft/openjdk8/make/common` into `-I/home/ft/open -j1 -dk8/make/common` it would appear. That would seem to be something attempting to enforce a maximum number of jobs on make (as opposed to the default unbounded behaviour of a bare `-j`).

Comment: I would also about what has gone on that has caused that `-I` argument to get duplicated so many times (though that is probably normal poor operation and nothing specifically broken/wrong with this run).

Comment: The only way anyone can help is if you locate the rule in the makefile which is invoking the sub-make, and show that.  Once the variables, etc. have been expanded by make as you see above the damage has been done, and without the content from the makefile (before the damage) we can't know what happened.

Comment: @MadScientist Most my experience with make has been as an end-user, do you have any suggestions on how I might do that? Searching for `-f adlc.make` turned up `@$(MAKE) -f adlc.make $(MFLAGS-adjusted)` in `hotspot/make/linux/makefiles/top.make` but that does not seem to be the top level make because of the additional parameters before the -f.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be part of a documented bug ([JDK-8028407](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8028407)). The fix for this was to downgrade my make to 3.82, which does manage to compile OpenJDK.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what did it for me. Apply the following patch inside the hotspot directory:

```
diff -r 87ee5ee27509 make/linux/makefiles/adjust-mflags.sh
--- a/make/linux/makefiles/adjust-mflags.sh Tue Mar 04 11:51:03 2014 -0800
+++ b/make/linux/makefiles/adjust-mflags.sh Wed Sep 30 16:51:55 2015 -0700
@@ -64,7 +64,6 @@
    echo "$MFLAGS" \
    | sed '
        s/^-/ -/
-       s/ -\([^    ][^     ]*\)j/ -\1 -j/
        s/ -j[0-9][0-9]*/ -j/
        s/ -j\([^   ]\)/ -j -\1/
        s/ -j/ -j'${HOTSPOT_BUILD_JOBS:-${default_build_jobs}}'/
```

It looks like one of the rules is just too wide and is matching random directories if they contain a j and happen to come after a dash.